# Calling phone with appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying on device make calls but device do not nothing...

This is my code, i'm using Appcelerator 4.4.0.201511241829, IOS 9.2

```
    var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    cancel: 0,
    buttonNames: ['Cancel', 'Ok'],
    message: "Are you sure?" 

    });

    dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e){

     if (e.index !== e.source.cancel){

        // IF WE ARE BUILDING FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES - TRY CALLING A FAKE NUMBER
        if(ENV_DEV){ 
              Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:00000000');
        }
        // ELSE IF WE ARE BUILDING PRODUCTION - THEN USE THE LISTED NUMBER
        else if(ENV_PRODUCTION){
             Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:00000000');
        }
    }  
});

dialog.show();
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for call a number seems correct. I suppose that nothing happen because `ENV_DEV` and `ENV_PRODUCTION` variables are not True, and so the two if statements are not satisfy.

First of all I suggest you to add an `else` statement for be sure that one one condition is satisfy. You can modify your code like this:

```
// IF WE ARE BUILDING FOR DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES - TRY CALLING A FAKE NUMBER
if(ENV_DEV){ 
    Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:00000000');
}
// ELSE IF WE ARE BUILDING PRODUCTION - THEN USE THE LISTED NUMBER
else if(ENV_PRODUCTION){
    Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:00000000');
}else{
    Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:00000000');
}
```

Secondly you can add a console log like this `Ti.API.info("yourMsg")` in each statements to check in which if you are.

I hope this is helpful

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your 'dial a number' code indeed seems correct. I would like to suggest you to structure your code a bit different, I'll give you an example from a recent project of mine.

You can configure phone numbers for your different environments(prod, dev) in your config.json(assuming you are working on an Alloy project, and not a Classic Titanium project), an example:

```
{
 "global": {
 "phoneNumber": tel:0032499001122"
},
 "env:development": {
  "phoneNumber": tel:0111111"
},
"env:test": {},
"env:production": {}, ..
```

This reduces the code in your click-handler to:

```
if (e.index !== e.source.cancel){
   Ti.Platform.openURL(Alloy.CFG.phoneNumber);
}
```

Because you pass the environment when you start the application, you do not longer need to check the environment in your code.

Don't forget to add your environment flag(-D development) if you run your app via the CLI, eg.

```
titanium build -p ios -T simulator -D development
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your atention, your code work too!.